# How do I prove that the weak law of large numbers holds?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, law-of-large-numbers

> We have given $X_1,X_2,...$ an i.i.d. sequence of random variables with $$\Bbb{P}(X_1=1)=\Bbb{P}(X_1=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$$ From class we know that then the characteristic function is $\Phi_{X_i}(t)=\cos(t)$ for all $t\in \Bbb{R}$ and we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \cos^n\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)=1$ for all $t\in \Bbb{R}$. Now I need to use these two to show that $$\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}\rightarrow 0$$in probability.

I have unfortunately no idea where to start and how to do this using the two points I listed above. Could maybe someone give me a hint?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Do you understand what the characteristic functions have to do with the law of large numbers?

Comment: @TrevorGunn Sorry I don‘t see what you mean.  I know the definition of the characteristic funktion but I don‘t see a connection

Comment: There is no reason to prove the weak law of large numbers this way, most people would calculate the variance of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and then use Chebyshev.  So if you are asked to do it this way, it is likely you are being asked to plug into some theorem that you were given about the limit of a characteristic function related to the limiting distribution of the random variables.  Even without this theorem, a first step is to compute the characteristic function of $X_1+ ... + X_n$, then of $(1/n)(X_1+...+X_n)$, and you can guess the theorem.

Comment: @Michael I see thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant theorems here are:

1. $X_n \Rightarrow X$ (convergence in distribution AKA weak convergence) if and only if the characteristic function of $X_n$ converges (pointwise) to the characteristic function of $X$. This is called Lévy's Continuity Theorem.
2. For a constant $c \in \mathbf{R}$, $X_n \Rightarrow c$ if and only if $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathbf P} c$. Usually convergence in probability is stronger but when the target is a constant the two modes of convergence are the same.